# How to break out of a while loop from a nested include file within PHP 7?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop that includes several complex functions as it loops through Mysql records.  One of the more simple tasks is to check the variable $city for a ñ symbol, and if $city contains a ñ symbol,  then the MySql record needs to be skipped, but the loop needs to continue for the rest of the Mysql records.

In the past, I have used "break;" for this, but I am receiving this error:

PHP Fatal error:  'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context

I have read that I should use "return false;" instead, but this does not seem to be working either.

Any help is much appreciated.

test.php

```
<?PHP

$query = "SELECT * FROM Cities limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $city = $row['City'];
    $city = "ñ";  // I hardcoded for testing
    require "test_function.php";
    echo "I should not see this if there is a ñ within $city \n\n";
}

?>
```

test_function.php

```
<?PHP

if( strpos( $city, "ñ" ) !== false) {
    echo "City $city contains a ñ.  Skipping...\n\n";
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you need that logical part (`if( strpos( $city, "ñ" )...`) anywhere else in your project ?

Comment: You cannot break from IF.  You can only break from FOR.  PHP7 change.

Comment: I think `continue` could do the trick, but I am not sure

Comment: I agree with @Tschitsch as if the first `$city` that contains a ñ, `break` would prevent all the other cities after to be checked

Comment: @HoldOffHunger He wants to break from `while`, that's allowed. You could never break from `if`, it's not a new change.

Comment: Besides why are you using `require` in a while loop.. `require` triggers random disk i/o which is slow (4 - 6 ms extra time per record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to skip one city, you should use `continue`, not `break`. `continue` goes to the next loop iteration, `break` ends the loop completely.

However, these statements have to be inside the loop body, they can't be in a function that it calls or an include file.

What you can do is have the include file set a variable, and check that after it.

test_function.php

```
<?PHP

if( strpos( $city, "ñ" ) !== false) {
    echo "City $city contains a ñ.  Skipping...\n\n";
    $skip_city = true;
} else {
    $skip_city = false;
}

?>
```

test.php

Comment: You can use `return` in if statements... But i wonder why he would use `require` in the while loop what will trigger random disk I/O which is slow.

Comment: Speed is not a concern in this case.  It's not a frontend web script.  It's a script for a backend graphic rendering server process.  Any speed loss for requiring a file is minimal compared to my rendering times.

Comment: Yes!  This works perfectly.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The file will already be in memory after the first `include`, so it doesn't use disk I/O every time.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you including other php file in the loop? Apply the condition within the loop and it would break out of the loop if condition is matched.

```
<?PHP

$query = "SELECT * FROM Cities limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $city = $row['City'];
    if( strpos( $city, "ñ" ) !== false) {
        echo "City $city contains a ñ.  Skipping...\n\n";
        break;
    }
    echo "I should not see this if there is a ñ within $city \n\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: In real my real script there are other conditions above this loop, and test_function.php is not always the same depending on these conditions.  I have hardcoded test_function.php above as an example.  Usually, it is "require $some_function";  Basically, sometimes a ñ is ok, but sometimes it's not depending on conditions above this example loop.

Answer (score 0):

This will break the iteration if that special character is found

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cities limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$isCharFound = false;

while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($isCharFound === false))
{
    $city = $row['City'];
    if( strpos( $city, "ñ" ) !== false) {
        echo "City $city contains a ñ.  Skipping...\n\n";
        $isCharFound = true;
        continue;
    }
    echo "I should not see this if there is a ñ within $city \n\n";
}
```

If you want to only skip the record that has special character

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cities limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $city = $row['City'];
    if( strpos( $city, "ñ" ) !== false) {
        echo "City $city contains a ñ.  Skipping...\n\n";
        continue;
    }
    echo "I should not see this if there is a ñ within $city \n\n";
}
```